# Нахождение произведения ряда

Tags: python

Дано натуральное число n. Вычислить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал наброски, находит значение, но понимаю, что неправильно, ибо у меня каждый элемент неправильный.

Вот мой код:

```
import math
n = int(input("n: "))
z = 1
for i in range(1, n+1):
    z *= math.cos(n)/math.sin(n)
print(z)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**способ 1:**

решаем задачу в лоб, т.е. для каждой дроби находим числитель и знаменатель, а затем вычисляем произведение дробей

```
res = 1

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    cos_n = 0
    sin_n = 0
    for j in range(1, n + 1):
        cos_n += math.cos(j)
        sin_n += math.sin(j)

    res *= cos_n / sin_n

print(res)
```

**способ 2:**

тут потребуется немного математики:

поскольку

```
sum(cos(i)) от 1 до n = csc(1/2) * sin(n/2) * cos((n+1)/2)

sum(sin(i)) от 1 до n = csc(1/2) * sin(n/2) * sin((n+1)/2)
```

(эту формулу можно получить через формулу Эйлера и комплексное представление тригонометрических функций и экспоненты)

то всю формулу можно записать в виде

```
res = prod(ctg((n+1)/2) от 1 до n
```

т.е. код можно сделать гораздо более простым :)

```
res = 1

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    res /= math.tan((n + 1) / 2)

print(res)
```

Answer (score 4):

можно отдельно хранить числитель и знаменатель, на каждой итерации прибавлять к ним косинус и синус, далее умножать результат их деления в общий результат

```
import math

n = int(input('n: '))

numerator = 0
denominator = 0
result = 1
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    numerator += math.cos(i)
    denominator += math.sin(i)
    result *= numerator / denominator

print(result)
```